# Session state is not available in root folder (.net)

Tags: asp.net, .net, session-state

I was given a webpage that has one application that is accessible via: www.mypage.com.

and the second one that is in the subfolder:

www.mypage.com/admin.

Both application has different web.config files, first is front end, second is back end. Now I need to make some kind of "front end preview". So when admin loges into backend and makes some manipulations, he has to navigate to the main page and see preview.

The problem is that login is stored in Session, but when admin navigates to the main page Session State is not seen.

How to solve this? 
I have read about Session States, but have not understood if this is what I need.

Comment: Are you required to use Session?

Answer (score 0):

A [session state server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or cookies are different solutions, this article might be helpful
http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/WebDev/ServerProgramming/ASPNET/sharing-asp-net-session-state-between-ap